# Avoid loops and memory issues in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let’s say I have two data frames df1 and df2. df1 has the raw data which is quite large (about 500 GB) and df2 has some filtering criteria which are used to select data from df1, do some computations, and save the output to azure blobs. What is the best approach to do this without relying on python loops. Currently what I have in place looks something like this:

```
for idx, row in df2.iterrows():
    filter1 = row[“filter1”]
    filter2 = row[“filter2”]
    df_filtered = df1.where((df1.col1>filter1) & (df1.col2<filter2))
    df_filtered.write.format('csv').option("delimiter", ",").save(outputpath, header = True)
```

Above solution is actually very slow and I am running into memory issues. I have thought of using an UDF but UDF has two problems for my scenario.

1. I cannot set spark configuration to save data to azure blobs within a UDF.
2. UDF returns a result to be appended to the data frame on which the function is being applied. Here, I need the function to be applied on df1 which has the raw data and is quite large but the output data needs be appended to df2 which is the smaller dataset with the filtering criteria.

Are there any alternative ways to design my solution to avoid memory issues?

Comment: is it possible that you can upload some samples of `df1` and `df2` into your question? also in the line `df.where...`, is it supposed to be `df2.where...`?

Comment: This looks more like pandas code than spark code no?